# MatrixLayout in mobile sapui5 app

Tags: mobile, sapui5

Im new in `sapui5` world. 
I want to structure my components in a js view but I don't know if I can use `sap.ui.commons` in mobile app, I read it's only for desktop applications. 
Has `sap.m` library some control to structure my components in a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not to use layouts that are not part of the sap.ui.layout library in mobile applications. Especially the MatrixLayout is known to be slow(er) on mobile devices - take a look at the Grid, which is better in most situations.

However, you can use every control in every app. When using XML you have to add the commons-library as a namespace. In JavaScript you must add the control to the bootstrap-attribute like this:

```
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.layout,sap.ui.commons"
```